# Problems installing JObject

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I had tried to install JObject in visual studio (both 4.6 and 3.5), via the NUGet option, but I get an error message:

> Error     Could not install package 'JObject 1.0.0'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v3.5', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: The error is quite clear explains the problem. You can't install that package to non-Core versions. The package's dependencies make that clear. In fact, 3.5 is no longer supported for quite some years now

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the error message. [JObject 1.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JObject/) only targets `.NET Core 2.0` which means that NuGet can't find a suitable version for you since you're targeting `.NET 3.5`/`.NET 4.6`. You will have to change your projects target framework to the appropriate `.NET Core` version.

**Edit:** Frauke is correct, only change to .NET Core if it's a really small project or if you know what you're doing.

Comment: Be aware that changing a .NET project to a .NET Core one is not a straightforward task.

Comment: Yes, Frauke is correct. Only change it if it's a really small project or if you're totally sure what you're doing.